# making variable synchronized and visible in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

1. If I have some synchronized method in java, how can I implement the same method by semaphores, without synchronized?  (Let's say that the method is a variable increment)
2. How can I make some variable visible to all threads and synchronized without using the synchronized keyword?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.If I have some synchronized method in java, how can I implement the same method by semaphores, without synchronized? (Let's say that the method is a variable increment)

You could use a binary semaphore (`new Semaphore(1)`), but you need to have a clear answer to the question *Why do I want to specifically use semaphores?*

While binary semaphores can be used for mutual exclusion, they are not exactly the same as mutexes, as their main purpose is mostly related to synchronization signaling. As an example, `release()` is not restricted to be called only by the thread that last successfully acquired the permit.

> 2.How can I make some variable visible to all threads and synchronized without using the synchronized keyword?

There are many ways to do that, but rather than enumerating them, I'll point you to the underlying language mechanics that apply for almost all of them. Basically, you need to guarantee [the visibility, the ordering and the atomicity](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.bg/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) of changes made to your variable.

There's the notion of the so-called *happens-before* ordering of actions in the execution of your program, and it can be used for reasoning whether what values will you see when you write to and read from your variable from different threads. You can say that *happens-before* can be used to guarantee the visibility and ordering of the changes made to your variable.

In addition to that, you need to ensure the atomicity of such changes. You need to know that stores are atomic, except for `long` and `double` values, and that composite operations (like incrementing using the `++` prefix or `++` postfix operator) are not atomic. There are ways to address these, but unless you understand what needs to be done, you won't be able to understand how a solution that someone offers you works (and if it's correct).

The Java Language Specification's Chapter 17 (Threads and Locks), and more specifically its Section 17.4 (Memory Model) explains in more details what *happens-before* is and what are the rules within which you can reason about it.

Comment: So mutex are better?

Comment: Mutex is better for mutual exclusion (not the biggest of revelations, I know). And in general, use the right tool for the job. To do that, first understand what's the job, then learn the tools. In your case, I strongly suspect that just using a `volatile` variable or some of the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` types will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have some synchronized method in java, how can I implement the
>   same method by semaphores, without synchronized? (Let's say that the
>   method is a variable increment)

Have a semaphore as an instance variable and initalize it with the value 1. When you enter the method acquire it and release it when you exit. This should be achieved in a try-finally block to ensure that the release happens without fail.

> How can I make some variable visible to all threads and synchronized
>   without using the synchronized keyword?

You could use the locks available in the Concurrency library or you could make it a volatile variable which ensures that the writes are immediately visible to all threads. But you would still need additional synchronization if multiple threads can write to this volatile variable.

Comment: How can I synchronize it without synchronized? By semaphore or something?

Comment: One way to do it would be to use a RentrantLock.  Before writing or reading the variable or a group of variables, acquire this lock and release the lock when you are finished. This will ensure that all changes to this variable (or a group) will be atomic and this will also ensure that changes made in one thread will be visible to another thread because they are all synchronized.